# sending email when error occured anywhere in aplication

Tags: java, ruby

I am working with a Rails application. I need it to send an email when an error occurs anywhere in the application, e.g. errors for undefined methods, variable not found etc.

If anyone had done something similar, please suggest me how to proceed.

Comment: Please add your code to get a better idea

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: This SO answer will help you to fulfill the need : http://stackoverflow.com/q/8709984/2383136

Comment: thanks for your reply..i don't know how to write code for this concept @Dinidu

Comment: https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification#actionmailer-configuration                                                                                                  i have done this problem by following this link..